# Use a returned datatable

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable

I have two classes.  I created a datatable in class 2 that gets returned.  I am trying to figure out how I can use these values in class 1.  I need to pass the datatable value in another method in class 1.

//Example:
In Class 2 I have:

```
public Datatable Mytable()
{         
    DataTable table = new DataTable(); 

table.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string)); 

table.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string)); 

      //get values for the data row here

return table;
}
```

In Class 1 I have:

```
public Method1 (String A, String B) 
//A and B need to represent the values in the Datatable from Class 2
{  string ab = "This is first datarow " + A + " This is second datarow " + B;

}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, do you want class 1 to call a method in class 2 to retrieve a datatable and do something with it.  Or do you want class 2 to create a datatable then call a method in class 1 and pass it in?

Comment: Hi, Yes I want Class 1 to call a method in class 2 (the "Mytable" method listed) and use the datarows as values.  The datatable will have a persons last name and a persons age.  I want class 1 to display this information in "Method1" as listed.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Class1 {
    public Class1() {
        var foo = new Class2();
        var table = foo.MyTable();
        Method1(table.Rows[0]["Column1"], table.Rows[0]["Column2"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look up how to use DataTables here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-foreach